# simple beginShape with p5 and webgl renderer

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm making a very basic example that uses p5.js and a canvas with WEBGL

```
function setup(){
    createCanvas(100, 100, WEBGL);
}

function draw(){
    beginShape(POINTS);
    vertex(0,0);
    endShape();
}
```

This is the full program. When i run this i get the following error

```
p5.js:31516 WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: enableVertexAttribArray: index out of rangep5.RendererGL._bindImmediateBuffers @ p5.js:31516p5.RendererGL.endShape @ p5.js:31447p5.endShape @ p5.js:15190draw @ sketch.js:8p5.redraw @ p5.js:14256(anonymous function) @ p5.js:9143
p5.js:31520 WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: vertexAttribPointer: index out of range
```

I'm using the latest version of p5.js (p5.js v0.5.4 October 01, 2016)
I have already read some other post about it being an issue with webgl optimizing unused attributes. But i'm not sure how i would go about fixing this in my simple example.

Comment: Weird. This seems to happen no matter what value is passed into `beginShape()`. You might want to create an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues

Comment: That's a good idea. I thought i was doing something wrong. I'll log an issue for it. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, and I couldn't find an existing issue on GitHub. So if you're doing something wrong, I'm also doing something wrong! :p

Comment: for future reference i have created an issue for this here: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1678 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer a problem, but it is a shape with one point will not show up on the canvas. If you want a point to be shown I recommend

```
function setup(){
    createCanvas(300, 300, WEBGL);
}

function draw(){
    background(230);
    beginShape();
        vertex(0,0);
        vertex(0,1);
    endShape();
}
```

which will look almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, but a misunderstanding :.
a shape is...a shape, not a point.
So it needs at least 2 vertex to exist as a minimum shape (a line), 3 for a triangle, 4 for rectangle and n for any ...shape..
P5 reference always talks about series::.

'After calling the beginShape() function, a series of vertex() commands must follow...’.